# Проблема с Fresco Image Viewer вместе RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть recyclerview, который показывает cardview с картинками. Я хочу чтобы по нажатию на cardview, картинки открывались на полный экран, для этого использую библиотеку Fresco Image Viewer.
В MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        Fresco.initialize(MainActivity.this);
    }
```

В адаптере:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new ImageViewer.Builder(view.getContext(), photosList).setStartPosition(position).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Когда нажимаю на cardview появляется черный экран.
Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка и как ее исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как FrescoImageViewer больше не поддерживается, то лучше мигрируйте на [StfalconImageViewer](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer)

И еще, лучше ckicklistener вешать в методе **onCreateViewHolder**, а не в **onBindViewHolder**